# Rails custom middleware is not recognised after upgrading from 6.0 to 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom middleware called LocaleMiddleware in my rails application that used to work fine with rails 6.0 but I get `uninitialized constant LocaleMiddleware` error. I checked the documentation (Release notes) but I didn't see anything related to custom middlewares changing. I had followed this article to write the middleware https://ieftimov.com/post/writing-rails-middleware/

Comment: Are you explicitly requiring the file? I would not expect autoloading the middleware to work reliably.

Comment: No, I am not requiring the middleware file explicitly. It used to find it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `require_relative "../app/lib/middlewares/my_middle_ware.rb"` where you're calling it, it might be in `config/application.rb`